# Connect to local SQL Server with Sequelize

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I recently set up a Local SQL Server Db for development of my node app. I'm having trouble trying to connect to it from my node app.

I was able to connect with sqlcmd using the command:

```
sqlcmd -S <hostname>\<instanceName>
```

I'm using the Sequelize cli in an attempt to run a migration on my development database.

my config.json is as follows:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "<my windows domain username>",
    "password": "<my windows domain password>",
    "database": "development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "instanceName": "LocalServer",
      "domain": "<my company's domain>"
    }
  }
}
```

I changed the name from EXPRESS to LOCALSERVER when I set it up (don't ask me why). I also set up it up to login with Windows authentication and SQL SERVER logins. I've gotten a variety of errors with the various configs I've tried, most recently:

```
ERROR: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined in 15000ms
```

I think I may not be understanding what values from SQL Server I should be passing to Sequelize. Where can I find the logs and view the actual connection string being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to use [sequelize-msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-msnodesqlv8) since I am using sqlserver, that is the only way to authenticate with windows. My final connection config object looked like this:

```
 {
 "development": {
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "dialectModulePath": "sequelize-msnodesqlv8",
    "dialectOptions": {
        "driver": "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",
        "trustedConnection": "true"
    },
    "username": "<my windows domain username>",
    "password": "<my windows domain password>",
    "database": "development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 1433,
    "logging": "true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi in my case by following this steps it has worked fine for me:

1 installing tedious -> npm install  tedious

2 then in DB utility node.js file ->

const Sequelize = require('sequelize').Sequelize;

sequelize = new Sequelize('DB_NAME', 'username', 'password', {
host: 'localhost',
dialect: 'mssql',
dialectOptions: {
instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVER'
}
});

module.exports = sequelize;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"port": "1433",` to your configuration. The undefined in your output is where the port should be, and I don't see it in your config.

I believe that the default port for MsSql is 1443.

If that doesn't work for you, create a new script with something like the following:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mssql',
    database: 'your-database-name',
    username: 'your-username',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '1433',
    password: 'your-password',
    logging: true,
})
```

Sequelize should give you more debugging info when run this way.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. The sequelize-cli was giving me trouble so I tried just connecting with new Sequelize() and then sequelize.authenticate(). I had to set the default port to 1433, but it looks like it is finding 127.0.0.1:1433 now. However, I am getting an error report: Login Failed for user 'myusername'. sqlstate: '28000', code: 18456

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with Mssql, so I probably won't be able to help you resolve this. I was able to find this, which sounds like it might be relevant: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2121736/error-message-when-you-try-to-authenticate-an-odbc-connection-to-your

Comment: Hmm, ya I saw that too. I'll keep digging. Thanks for your help though, you got me one step closer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into this and found that my SQL Server Browser service was stopped.  Once I started the service from SQL Server Configuration Manager I was able to connect.

It is documented in the Requirements in the GitHub project

> Please make sure MS SQL Server **TCP/IP connection** is enabled and
>   **Server Browsing** is up and running.

https://github.com/ErenYatkin/sequelizeJS-mssql

Answer (score 0):

if someone is still struggling with this, in my case, I solved it by configuring my local SQL Server Express to be accessible via network

(see link to see how https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configuring-sql-server-2016-express-on-lan-for-c-sharp-connection-string/)

And then configured sequelize with

host: 'localhost',
port: '1433',

Comment: The question was also about using Windows authentification for MS SQL Server logon, i guess that by "accessible" you mean "integrated authentication" . You should mention that point in your answer.

Comment: Actually, he did mention setting it up to "login with Windows authentication and SQL SERVER logins". I'm suggesting an updated answer that might not cause compatibility issues because sequelize-msnodesqlv8 says "May not be compatible with msnodesqlv8 > 0.3.2" as of today

The answer above suggests using SQL Server Authentications instead, if you'll do that, you'll need to setup your local SQL Server to be accessible through network to configure it correctly in Sequelize. You'll actually use SQL Server Authentication in prod, this is your chance to test your configs.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to connect sequelize with their mssql domain account, here's the code

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', null, null, {
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectOptions: {
    authentication: {
      type: 'ntlm',
      options: {
        domain: 'yourDomain',
        userName: 'username',
        password: 'password'
      }
    },
    options: {
      instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the documentation link
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/dialect-specific-things.html

If this doesn't work, try changing instanceName value to 'MSSQLSERVER'.